# Definition of Baire sets

Tags: general-topology

A Baire set is usually defined as an element of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the compact $G_\delta$-sets. Halmos defines a Baire set in the Stone space of a Boolean algebra as an element of the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the clopen sets. Are these two definitions equivalent in the Stone space of a Boolean algebra and, more generally, in a compact Hausdorff space?

(I know that every compact set in a Hausdorff space is closed. Since the Stone space of a Boolean algebra is Hausdorff and every clopen set is closed, I can see a connection between the two definitions. But what about $G_\delta$-sets?)

Answer (score 1):

In general spaces these algebras can be different: e.g. in $\Bbb R$ in the discrete topology the compact $G_\delta$ sets are just the finite sets, and so we get the countable-cocountable algebra as the Baire sets in that sense, while all subsets are clopen and so in the other sense we just get the power set.

A similar example is the Dieudonné measure on $\omega_1$ (exercise 10 on 231 in Halmos' book).

Of course in a compact Hausdorff space all clopen sets are compact $G_\delta$'s, so then $\sigma(\mathcal{F} \cap \mathcal{T}) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{T}_\delta \cap \mathcal{K})$ (where I denote by $\mathcal{F}$ all closed subsets, $\mathcal{K}$ all compact subsets, and by $\mathcal{T}_\delta$ all $G_\delta$ sets).

If $X$ is moreover zero-dimensional (so a Boolean space), Theorem C. in Halmos' Measure Theory (p. 221) implies that $\sigma(\mathcal{T}_\delta \cap \mathcal{K}) \subseteq \sigma(\mathcal{F} \cap \mathcal{T})$ (the clopen sets form a base, after all).

So in the special case of Boolean spaces these two definitions do coincide.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer still another definition:  The $\sigma$-algebra generated by zero-sets (sets of the form $\{x : f(x) = 0\}$ where $f$ is a real-valued continuous function.  This is appropriate for a general completey regular Hausdorff space.

The Halmos definition is appropriate for locally compact Hausdorff spaces.  And note: Didn't Halmos actually say: the $\sigma$-ring generated by the compact $G_\delta$ sets.

The Stone space definition is appropriate for, well, Stone spaces.  Spaces with lots and lots of clopen sets.

In completely regular Hausdorff spaces, we have
$$
\sigma\big(\text{compact $G_\delta$ sets}\big) \subseteq
\sigma\big(\text{zero sets}\big) \subseteq
\sigma\big(\text{closed $G_\delta$ sets}\big)
$$
In general, none of these is equality.  In Euclidean space they are all equal.  In compact Hausdorff spaces (in particular, in Stone spaces) they are all equal.

---

A great book is:

*Gillman, Leonard; Jerison, Meyer*, Rings of continuous functions., Mineola, NY: Dover Publications (ISBN 978-0-486-81688-3). ix, 300 p. (2017). [ZBL1380.46022](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1380.46022).

Comment: Right ... $\sigma$-ring, not $\sigma$-algebra.  Fixing.